# Overloading operators *only* for the base class

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

In C#, I have a base class `Hex` where I'm overloading its equality operators like so:

```
public class Hex {
    #region Equality

    public static bool operator ==(Hex a, Hex b) {
        if (a is null) { return b is null; }
        if (b is null) { return false; }
        // Two hex instances are equal if their coordinates match
        return a.Q == b.Q && a.R == b.R && a.S == b.S;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Hex a, Hex b) { return !(a == b); }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Hex x && this == x;

    #endregion
}
```

I extend the class to hold some extra info:

```
public class HexWithMeta : Hex {
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

I then expected the following method to return false, yet it returns true:

```
public bool DoTest() {
    var h1 = new HexWithMeta(1, 1, -2);
    var h2 = new HexWithMeta(1, 1, -2);
    return h1 == h2;
}
```

This seems to be because `h1 == h2` is calling the overloaded `==` operator on the `Hex` class.  However, I'm comparing `HexWithMeta` objects, not `Hex` objects.  How can I get `==` to compare referential equality for classes like `HexWithMeta` that extend `Hex`, but use the custom operator code for comparing the base `Hex` class instances?

Comment: You could use `typeof(Hex) == a.GetType()` condition (and the same for `b`) in your operator implementations.

Comment: Could you post it as an answer with sample implementation that I can accept?

Comment: If you have 2 instances of `HexWithMeta` and they their respective Q, R, and S are all equal but their OwnerId's are different, do you consider those instances of `HexWithMeta` to be equal?!

Comment: @RickDavin No.  I don't consider two different instances of `HexWithMeta` to be equal, ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard implementation of Equality (as generated by R#) should look like this:

```
public class MyClass : IEquatable<MyClass>
{
    private int myProperty;
    public static bool operator ==(MyClass left, MyClass right) => Equals(left, right);
    public static bool operator !=(MyClass left, MyClass right) => !Equals(left, right);
    public bool Equals(MyClass other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return myProperty == other.myProperty;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((MyClass)obj);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() => myProperty;
}
```

Notably the `obj.GetType() != this.GetType()` that checks that the actual types match.

Note that you should also override the equality members for `HexWithMeta`, because not doing so would be terribly confusing. And I really do not understand why you expect your example *not* to compare true, if you create two objects with the same parameters I would very much expect them to compare identical.

If you want to do anything fancy with comparison I would highly recommend instead creating an implementation of the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface. This should also be the interface you should accept whenever you compare any type of generic object. Use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to get a default implementation for a generic type.

Comment: They have the same parameters passed to the constructors, but `HexWithMeta` stores extra pieces of meta-information on top of the base `Hex`, so it's entirely possible that they could not be considered equal.  Therefore I'm wanting a simple referential equality check for that class, and really, any class that extends `Hex` as I strongly suspect I'll always do that in order to store extra information.

Comment: @Jez Stick to *either* reference equality or value equality. Mixing both within the same type hierarchy sounds like an invitation for mistakes and bugs. You should try to avoid surprising your colleges, and having both value or reference equality in that way would be very surprising to me at least.

Comment: What would you suggest if value equality makes sense in one class but reference equality in another?

Comment: @Jez If you for some reason need value equality in some cases, create a EqualityComparer for that particular case, letting the user chose if reference or value equality is more appropriate on a case by case basis. And making the choice more obvious

Comment: So there's no way for me to use the `==` operator in that case to compare the objects by value when they're `Hex`es?

Comment: @Jez You *can* implement the equals operator however you want. But *can* and *should* are different things.  You *should* keep your logic simple, so that you can explain it to someone else in one sentence, or remember how it works in a year.

Comment: OK, but it seems rather straightforward to me.  `Hex` is a very basic class and its identity can be defined by its coordinates.  As soon as you get more complex than that, storing arbitrary extra data, it makes sense to me to just start comparing instances the default way.

Comment: @Jez To me that just sounds like you should be using composition instead of inheritance. Make Hex sealed (and use value equality), if you want to associate it with some other data, use a Composite class, a (value)tuple, or a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, I was about 50/50 on composition vs inheritance.  I knew I'd choose the wrong one.  Would you make Hex a struct in addition?  That way, value equality would be by default.

Comment: @Jez Yes, if it only has 3 fields and follows value-semantics I would make it a readonly struct, That should make the behavior of the type fairly obvious. And minimize the possibility of mistakes.

Comment: Could it also be appropriate to turn it into a record class?

Comment: @Jez Maybe, it depend on the usage. No way for us to tell without more information on how it is intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the entire comparison logic including the compare-by-reference logic for types deriving from `Hex` in the `Hex` operator overloads. For example, the `==` operator in *Hex* could look like this:

```
public static bool operator ==(Hex a, Hex b)
    => (a is null) ? b is null
        : (b is null) ? false
        // Equality-by-reference for any instances of types derived from Hex
        : (a.GetType() != typeof(Hex) || b.GetType() != typeof(Hex)) ? object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)
        // Two instances of type Hex are equal if their coordinates match
        : a.Q == b.Q && a.R == b.R && a.S == b.S;
```